# Wrapper not working HTML

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to do some html for an assignment, but when I try this code, the purple overlaps the header. Eventually I realized that was because the "100%" is inherited from the "header" div, even though it is closed. Is there any way you can get the purple to go UNDER the nav bar? (I cannot remove the percentage height) And while you are at it, maybe a fix for the fact that the header is separate from the navigation bar?

```
  <html>
     <head>
     <style type="text/css">
        body {
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
    }
        #header {
        color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        height: 70px;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
        background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
        }
    a {
        color: orange;
         text-decoration: none;
        }

    li {
        display: inline;
    }

    .main {
        width: 32%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FF66CC;
        overflow:auto;
            }
    #nav {
        background-color: lightblue;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Dog</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</li>
            <li><a href="">Cat</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</li>
            <li><a href="">Bird</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</li>
            <li><a href="">Fish</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</li>
            <li><a href="">Robot</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</li>
            <li><a href="">Snake</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
            <br /></li></ul></div><p><br /></p>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
    <p>Stique condimentum. Proin gravida felis eros, id hendrerit mi scelerisque pharetra. In ultricies pharetra semper. Suspendisse potenti. In risus lectus, pretium id tempus at, blandit at leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam eu arcu id arcu eleifend accumsan eget vitae sapien. Sed sit amet felis non elit hendrerit pharetra et a tortor. Etiam at vehicula sapien. Donec volutpat est vel massa placerat, in mollis lorem aliquet. Proin convallis, tortor vel pellentesque laoreet, leo ligula venenatis orci, at porttitor diam tellus non felis. Quisque gravida, nibh vel posuere mattis, dui quam rhoncus felis, ut luctus erat risus et justo.tae egestas. Quisque posuere malesuada faucibus. Nulla molestie fermentum elit, vel rhoncus purus. Nunc porttitor sed magna non ultricies. Integer congue congue mollis. Nunc mollis ac nisl sit amet pellentesque. Proin feugiat eros justo, eu egestas purus pretium quis. Mauris risus nisl, mattis ut justo eu, pellentesque tincidunt leo. Mauris fermentum suscipit nunc et aliquam. Ut quis tempor odio. Phasellus ante nisl, interdum iaculis facilisis a, pretium quis elit. Sed sit amet metus id tortor cursus euismod. Proin bibendum augue a tellus adipiscing dictum. Fusce ac ante sit amet lectus auctor suscipit sed eget dolor. Vestibulum vel laoreet purus. Nullam a porttitor neque.

    Cras magna metus, aliquam et metus id, tincidunt blandit justo. Maecenas blandit, nunc et iaculis mattis, odio leo pharetra velit, quis dictum sem leo ac lorem. Duis gravida suscipit nibh, ut consequat turpis blandit quis. Integer vitae orci ullamcorper, tempor enim non, elementum sem. Morbi quis nisl urna. Vestibulum sagittis rutrum eros, eu bibendum tortor posuere a. Donec et purus at sem sagittis laoreet at quis odio. Nullam nisl odio, interdum id varius in, pharetra eu nisi.

    Nam scelerisque eros sit amet pellentesque aliquam. Sed dui massa, malesuada vel euismod non, placerat id diam. d hendrerit mi scelerisque pharetra. In ultricies phare.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you post your html code in http://jsbin.com.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/cVGHT/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rearrange the HTML and the Css, as this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sns9z/):

Basically, make the `#nav` float:

```
   #nav {
    float: right;
    width: 68%;
   [....your code....]
   }
```

*Suggestion, if i can:*

clean-up the HTML structure, it seems a little not *functional*, either [*semantic*](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/18/the-importance-of-sections/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper {
    top: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
#header {
    height: 70px;
}
```

This is causing the navbar in a critical situation as the **#nav** is child of **#header**.
Change the height as desired and you will get your solution. For example a `height` of *117px* is good for desktop screen.